# How to change selected DropDownList item via JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to change the selected option of my ASP.NET DropDownList using JS / JQuery and get the selected Value later on.

In DOM:

```
<select id="myDDL" name="myDDL">
  <option selected="selected" value="0"> Option 1 </option>
  <option value="1"> Option 2 </option>
  <option value="2"> Option 3 </option>
</select>
```

I tried 
`$("#myDDL").val(1);` but this does not work 100%. The text of it will be displayed ("Option 2") but there is still the first option selected in DOM.

I want to get the selectedValue in a code behind button onclick method using

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int val = myDDL.SelectedValue;
  ...
}
```

but this returns 0 instead of 1, which means Option 1 is still selected.

So what do I have to do to set the second option correctly?
And why does the displayed text change to the one of option 2, but not the selected attribut?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was that the ViewState of the DropDownList was disabled.

Adding

```
myDDL.EnableViewState = true;
```

fixed the problem.

Now, using

```
$("#myDDL").val(1);
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex), like so:

```js
let select = document.getElementById("myDDL");
select.options.selectedIndex = 1;
```

```html
<select id="myDDL" name="myDDL">
  <option selected="selected" value="0"> Option 1 </option>
  <option value="1"> Option 2 </option>
  <option value="2"> Option 3 </option>
</select>
```

> The HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex is a long that reflects the index of the first or last selected  element, depending on the value of multiple. The value -1 indicates that no element is selected.

Comment: Using this has the same result. In the UI you will see "Option 2" but in code behind there is still the first Item with "Option 1" selected.

Comment: this is a asp:DropDownList. I want to get the selectedValue out of a button onclick method that is a c# event function. I should get the value using myDDL.SelectedValue; but this returns 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Please change the question with all these details; we would neeed a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myDDL').change(function() {
        val= $('#myDDL :selected').map(function(i, el) {
            return $(el).val();
        }).get();
        console.log(val);
    });
```